# Positioning Div elements by percentage

Tags: javascript, css

I currently have a html page which needs to create a div which is the full width of the page. I am trying to organize divs within that position by percentage rather that px. .question is the class associated with the div which needs to be full page

My css code looks as follows :

```
.question {
        position: absolute;
        min-height: 100%;
        min-width: 100%;
      }

      #titlepage{
        position: relative;
        top: 30%;
        width: 50%;
        text-align: center;
        overflow: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
      }

      html, body {
        background-color: #A0B8C8;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
      }

<body ontouchmove="BlockMove(event);">
      <div class="question">
        <div id="titlepage">
          <h1> test data </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
```

The aim is for the #titlepage div to be 30% of screen size from the top and centered.

At the minute it is 30% from top, but the margin auto isn't setting it to be centered horizontally.

Any help is appreciated, as well as an explanation why.

Thank you

*Edit html added. It doeesn't appear to work with mine. Is it possible that something is overriding it?

**Edit. I appear to have fixed it by adding right:0; left:0;
so it looks like this :

```
.titlepage{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    right: 0; left: 0;    
  }
```

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Could you post your HTML as well?

Comment: You need to show your HTML as well.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/wuyuqetefe/1/edit It seems to work as you described?

Comment: Since this is CSS positioning the javascript tag is misplaced

Comment: That example does work, but my div containers are within each other, rather than one after the other

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
top: 30%;
```

To

```
height: 30%
```

I hope that's what you are asking.

Comment: I wish to reposition the div, not scale it. The positioning of it is just not centered horizontally